# <pre> elements on blog don't scroll for overflow-x

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

On Ask Different, content in a `<pre>` element that is wider than the box will cause the box to scroll (CSS `overflow-x: scroll;`).

On the Ask Different Blog, that doesn't happen. The too-wide content just overflows out of the box:

[image]

You can see the problem live on [this blog post](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/applescript-sales-tax-calculator-variables-operations-and-comments/).

Adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to the `<pre>` fixes the issue; could one of the people with access to the theme make this tweak?

Comment: I'll fix this very soon.

Comment: @Jin Great, much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is live. Please hard refresh.